# How I could print everything that happens in process?

Tags: java, groovy, process

print everything that happens  in process in groovy

please help me

this is my code

```
try {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Start..."

def proc =["/bin/sh",      "-c","./commandx"].execute()

    proc.waitForOrKill(420 * 1000)

    def output = proc.text?.trim()

    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Output = ${output}"

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("[${LocalTime.now()}] Process killed before completing! 6")
} finally {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] End..."
}
```

Comment: I don't have any `commandx` but if I run your code with `ls` it pretty much does what you're asking for.

Comment: I solve with in.withreader , very thankyou for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [`waitForProcessOutput`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)):

> Gets the output and error streams from a process and reads them to keep the process from blocking due to a full output buffer. The processed stream data is appended to the supplied OutputStream. For this, two Threads are started, but join()ed, so we wait. As implied by the waitFor... name, we also wait until we finish as well. Finally, the input, output and error streams are closed.

So I guess this is the code you are looking for:

```
try {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Start..."
    def proc =["/bin/sh", "-c", "./commandx"].execute()
    proc.waitForOrKill(420 * 1000)
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("[${LocalTime.now()}] Process killed before completing! 6")
} finally {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] End..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this

```
try {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Start..."

def proc =["/bin/sh",      "-c","./commandx"].execute()

proc.in.withReader { r -> 
  r.eachLine { line -> 
    // some token processing
    println "batfile output> ${line.toUpperCase()}"
  }
}

    proc.waitForOrKill(420 * 1000)


    def output = proc.text?.trim()

    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] Output = ${output}"

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("[${LocalTime.now()}] Process killed before completing! 6")
} finally {
    println "[${LocalTime.now()}] End..."
}
```